# Discord бот на GoLang

Tags: golang, discord

Здраствуйте, я скачал Discord бота на Go, сам на Go не пишу, подскажите что не так.

```
C:\Users\mega_ultra_man\Downloads\ImpactBot-master\ImpactBot-master>go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
.\main.go:47:21: undefined: onUserJoin
.\main.go:48:21: undefined: onMessageSent
.\main.go:49:21: undefined: onMessageReactedTo
.\main.go:51:21: undefined: onMessageSent2
.\main.go:52:21: undefined: onMessageSentCommandHandler
.\main.go:53:21: undefined: onUserJoin2
.\main.go:54:21: undefined: onVoiceStateUpdate
.\main.go:55:21: undefined: onUserJoin3
.\main.go:56:21: undefined: onReady2
.\main.go:57:21: undefined: onGuildMemberUpdate
.\main.go:57:21: too many errors
```

Код бота - [тык](https://github.com/ImpactDevelopment/ImpactBot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main.go` требует методы, которые лежат в соседних файлах. в Go все файлы в одной "папке" называются пакетом. Вам надо

- либо передавать пути до всех, например, так `go run ./main.go ./chess.go ./command.go ....`
- либо указать директорию `go run ./`
- либо собрать в бинарь и запустить бинарь `go build -o ./app ./`, `./app`

Comment: Спасибо, вышла новая проблема

`No .env file found
panic: Must set environment variable DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.init.0()
        C:/Users/mega_ultra_man/Downloads/ImpactBot-master/ImpactBot-master/main.go:31 +0x3d0
exit status 2`

Comment: все правильно. приложение требует .env файл рядом с ним. внутри должны быть определенные переменные, например DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN